# Is there any way to prevent activity from closing while minimizing the app?

Tags: java, android

My main activity say A is open and by firing an alarm I am opening another activity say B using following code
`final Intent intent = new Intent(context, BasicTemplateActivity.class)
                                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);`
when this BasicTemplateActivity is Foreground and I am minimizing the app this activity is dismissing. I want to make that activity as sticky. It should not close while minimizing.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I am pretty much sure its not closing its in different Task because of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ..

Comment: If its not closing then is there any way to bring it to foreground?